# Android: how to display keypad

Tags: android, keypad, android-keypad

i am developing simple adroid application. I main program i need to see kaypad(just letters). I have tried to add buttons and then and caption, events, but it takes a lot of time to configure app. Maybe there is another way to display simple letter keypad?

Answer (score 2):

```
EditText EditTextName=findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(EditTextName), 0);
```

write above code in edittext focus listener.Then u got the keypad whenever that view has focus

Comment: Ok, thx. i will try. But how to set position of this element?

Comment: Gedzis i did not understand your comment.Can u explain clearly